# Using a directory other than .git

Tags: git, debugging, version-control, perforce

tl;dr: Multiple repos on top of each other. I need this because of reasons.

I have a large project checked out in Perforce, and am sick and tired of dicking about with shelves, not being able to record experimental branches without a lot of manual labour, and not being able to revert mistakes in large chunks of code that cannot be committed to the central repository individually.

Therefore, in between "official" Perforce commits, I have taken to maintaining Git repos inside the same workspace (because our build process is idiotically integrated with Perforce) which can then have their own branches, commit history, and so on.

The problem I am faced with is that because of limited disk space and glacial download speeds, I am often forced to re-purpose a Perforce checkout for multiple tasks. This necessitates switching between work in git (without which doing any productive work at all would be impossible). However, since syncing Perforce with git causes merge conflicts, each git checkout only manages a small subset of files, depending on the task at hand. This presents a problem when mass-ignoring all of the other files, and keeping the number of branches manageable.

I would like to maintain a number of independent .gits at the top level of my P4 checkout, and so need to be able to specify the name of the ".git" directory and ".gitignore" file explicitly on invocation or via an environment variable.

Unfortunately because of the way git handles symlinks, I can't keep these individual repos separate from the P4 checkout without having to manually sync them back and forth, which is error-prone.

Comment: That sounds like a nightmare.  Is your server not new enough for you to be able to use Perforce's built-in DVCS mode that does all that local branching stuff?

Comment: @SamStafford hahaha no (and it would still be worse than using Git)

Comment: Quit. Get a new job.

Comment: Sparse checkout may be helpful in your case, although I don’t have a ready-made recipe off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are environment variables `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` that control which repo and working directory git commands will affect. There are also options to the git command itself, called `--work-tree` and `--git-dir`.

So, you can either define simple shell aliases that change the environment for each of your projects:

```
alias work_on_foo='export GIT_DIR=mybigproject/.foo.git; export GIT_WORK_TREE=mybigproject'
```

Or a [shim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(computing)) that would append desired options to git command:

```
alias foogit='git --git-dir=mybigproject/.foo.git --work-tree=mybigproject'
```

You can take a look at my dotfiles repo for [examples](https://github.com/jan-warchol/my-dotfiles/blob/devel/.config/bash/dotfiles.sh) of both methods, including some extra logic like adding special handling for some git subcommands.

As for `.gitignore`, I don't think there is an env variable for that, but you can use `info/exclude` file (it should be put in `.git`) for exactly the same purpose (it has the same syntax, just isn't part of the repository data like `.gitignore` is. Or, you could use git config setting named `core.excludesfile` and set it differently in each .git/config to point to appropriate file.

Answer (score 0):

I am faced with a similar situation, however I use a combination of git-p4 and git workspaces.

But it sounds like that wouldn't work for you because of your limited disk space problem. If you could just increase disk space you could then have a single git repo and multiple git workspaces.